# Why do CodeIgniter projects sometimes include composer.phar package?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, doctrine, composer-php

I'm new to Composer and in my current project I would like to install a bunch of PHP libraries like:

1. Doctrine
2. Security Library (Which i have no idea but looking for in CodeIgniter)
3. Bootstrap layout libraries and other when necessary

For that matter , I would like to use **Composer** based library management in my application,

and i get confused that if i have to include `composer.phar` on my project directory or not.

since i have it on my environment path and I can run Composer form command line .

How can integrate the above libraries into my `codeigniter` application then..

Appreciate your toughs!

Comment: The `composer.phar` file should not be committed. The user either installs it into the folder when setting up the project, or installs it globally on the machine. If you already have it installed, you don't need another copy.

Comment: (As an aside: please spell-check your posts before making them. It's fine if your first language is not English, but a quick-read through really does reduce the amount of edit work required to make them readable for others. Thanks!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composer.phar file is an executable and it should not be committed. What it actually does is that it looks in your composer.json file and there you can declare some more dependencies (libraries for example) and their version:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "*"
    }
}
```

The version in this case is declared with "*" so Composer will get the latest version. This is very useful if there are more people on the project, to make sure all of them have the same version of dependencies installed (so the composer.json file must be committed).

If you run "composer.phar update" on the other hand, this will get the latest version of all dependencies, no matter the version placed in composer.json and updates the lock file with the new versions.